# Pending tx with parity through geth console

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, parity

I am having issues with the current version of geth 1.8. Thus, I tried using parity and got a node synced. I want to use web3 and because of familiarly, I want to use parity with the geth console which I did so successfully. However, much to my dismay it appears that familiar objects and functions I had been using with geth like`txpool.content` no longer works. Is there a way to get pending tx on the geth console with a parity node?

Answer (score 0):

You can view [parity_pendingTransactions](https://wiki.parity.io/JSONRPC-parity-module#parity_pendingtransactions) and [parity_pendingtransactionsstats](https://wiki.parity.io/JSONRPC-parity-module#parity_pendingtransactionsstats), these might help.

Comment: Thanks. I am used to geth and the JavaScript console. But I’m not sure how to interact with parity. If I type what you said into the terminal window where my node is syncing, nothing happens. Is there a guide how to interact with parity?

Comment: on attaching geth console with parity node(which you done already), you will find parity module along with web3,net,eth etc. And under parity module you'll find these functions.

Comment: Sorry could you explain a little further about “finding the parity module”?

Comment: can you see other modules like web3,eth,net etc

Comment: on attached geth console just write parity , if module exists, it will show

Comment: I wrote parity and it says reference error. Also tried parity. and pressed tab. And finally, I tried parity.parity_pendingTransactions